# PHP, _POST["variable"] and strange encoding geojson data

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

What is the remedium for recover right encoding char data from **_POST["variable"]** with geojson?

On the server received **_POST["variable"]** value is equal to (for example)

**"\"geometry\": { \"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\":**

but it has to have value like this (it looks like that on the client with utf-8 encoding):

**"geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":**

It looks like **\"** has to be change only to **"** but ordinary replace dosen't give efect in further geojson data parsing

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode on _POST["variable"] to get the Json format.

Comment: I do it but on data with "\ I obtain epty value:(